# python find all cycles of large undirected graph(374 nodes and 1376 edges)?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I want to find all cycles in my undirected graph, let me list the graph first:

```
graph = [['BTC', 'ETH'], ['BTC', 'LTC'], ['BTC', 'BNB'], ['BTC', 'NEO'], ['BTC', 'GAS'], ['BTC', 'WTC'], ['BTC', 'LRC'], ['BTC', 'QTUM'], ['BTC', 'ZRX'], ['BTC', 'KNC'], ['BTC', 'SNM'], ['BTC', 'IOTA'], ['BTC', 'LINK'], ['BTC', 'MTL'], ['BTC', 'EOS'], ['BTC', 'SNT'], ['BTC', 'ETC'], ['BTC', 'ZEC'], ['BTC', 'BNT'], ['BTC', 'AST'], ['BTC', 'DASH'], ['BTC', 'OAX'], ['BTC', 'REQ'], ['BTC', 'VIB'], ['BTC', 'TRX'], ['BTC', 'POWR'], ['BTC', 'XRP'], ['BTC', 'ENJ'], ['BTC', 'STORJ'], ['BTC', 'KMD'], ['BTC', 'NULS'], ['BTC', 'XMR'], ['BTC', 'AMB'], ['BTC', 'BAT'], ['BTC', 'LSK'], ['BTC', 'MANA'], ['BTC', 'ADX'], ['BTC', 'ADA'], ['BTC', 'XLM'], ['BTC', 'WAVES'], ['BTC', 'ICX'], ['BTC', 'ELF'], ['BTC', 'RLC'], ['BTC', 'PIVX'], ['BTC', 'IOST'], ['BTC', 'STEEM'], ['BTC', 'BLZ'], ['BTC', 'ZIL'], ['BTC', 'ONT'], ['BTC', 'WAN'], ['BTC', 'SYS'], ['BTC', 'LOOM'], ['BTC', 'ZEN'], ['BTC', 'THETA'], ['BTC', 'IOTX'], ['BTC', 'QKC'], ['BTC', 'DATA'], ['BTC', 'ARDR'], ['BTC', 'VET'], ['BTC', 'DOCK'], ['BTC', 'RVN'], ['BTC', 'DCR'], ['BTC', 'REN'], ['BTC', 'ONG'], ['BTC', 'FET'], ['BTC', 'CELR'], ['BTC', 'MATIC'], ['BTC', 'ATOM'], ['BTC', 'PHB'], ['BTC', 'TFUEL'], ['BTC', 'ONE'], ['BTC', 'FTM'], ['BTC', 'ALGO'], ['BTC', 'DOGE'], ['BTC', 'DUSK'], ['BTC', 'ANKR'], ['BTC', 'COS'], ['BTC', 'TOMO'], ['BTC', 'CHZ'], ['BTC', 'BAND'], ['BTC', 'XTZ'], ['BTC', 'HBAR'], ['BTC', 'NKN'], ['BTC', 'STX'], ['BTC', 'KAVA'], ['BTC', 'ARPA'], ['BTC', 'CTXC'], ['BTC', 'BCH'], ['BTC', 'VITE'], ['BTC', 'OGN'], ['BTC', 'DREP'], ['BTC', 'LTO'], ['BTC', 'COTI'], ['BTC', 'STPT'], ['BTC', 'SOL'], ['BTC', 'CTSI'], ['BTC', 'HIVE'], ['BTC', 'CHR'], ['BTC', 'MDT'], ['BTC', 'DGB'], ['BTC', 'COMP'], ['BTC', 'SXP'], ['BTC', 'SNX'], ['BTC', 'IRIS'], ['BTC', 'MKR'], ['BTC', 'RUNE'], ['BTC', 'FIO'], ['BTC', 'AVA'], ['BTC', 'BAL'], ['BTC', 'YFI'], ['BTC', 'JST'], ['BTC', 'ANT'], ['BTC', 'CRV'], ['BTC', 'SAND'], ['BTC', 'OCEAN'], ['BTC', 'NMR'], ['BTC', 'DOT'], ['BTC', 'IDEX'], ['BTC', 'PAXG'], ['BTC', 'TRB'], ['BTC', 'WBTC'], ['BTC', 'SUSHI'], ['BTC', 'KSM'], ['BTC', 'EGLD'], ['BTC', 'DIA'], ['BTC', 'UMA'], ['BTC', 'BEL'], ['BTC', 'WING'], ['BTC', 'UNI'], ['BTC', 'OXT'], ['BTC', 'AVAX'], ['BTC', 'FLM'], ['BTC', 'SCRT'], ['BTC', 'ORN'], ['BTC', 'UTK'], ['BTC', 'XVS'], ['BTC', 'ALPHA'], ['BTC', 'VIDT'], ['BTC', 'AAVE'], ['BTC', 'NEAR'], ['BTC', 'FIL'], ['BTC', 'INJ'], ['BTC', 'AERGO'], ['BTC', 'AUDIO'], ['BTC', 'CTK'], ['BTC', 'AXS'], ['BTC', 'HARD'], ['BTC', 'STRAX'], ['BTC', 'FOR'], ['BTC', 'UNFI'], ['BTC', 'ROSE'], ['BTC', 'SKL'], ['BTC', 'GLM'], ['BTC', 'GRT'], ['BTC', 'PSG'], ['BTC', '1INCH'], ['BTC', 'OG'], ['BTC', 'CELO'], ['BTC', 'RIF'], ['BTC', 'TRU'], ['BTC', 'TWT'], ['BTC', 'FIRO'], ['BTC', 'LIT'], ['BTC', 'SFP'], ['BTC', 'FXS'], ['BTC', 'DODO'], ['BTC', 'FRONT'], ['BTC', 'CAKE'], ['BTC', 'AUCTION'], ['BTC', 'PHA'], ['BTC', 'TVK'], ['BTC', 'BADGER'], ['BTC', 'FIS'], ['BTC', 'OM'], ['BTC', 'POND'], ['BTC', 'DEGO'], ['BTC', 'ALICE'], ['BTC', 'LINA'], ['BTC', 'PERP'], ['BTC', 'SUPER'], ['BTC', 'CFX'], ['BTC', 'TKO'], ['BTC', 'TLM'], ['BTC', 'FORTH'], ['BTC', 'ICP'], ['BTC', 'AR'], ['BTC', 'POLS'], ['BTC', 'MDX'], ['BTC', 'LPT'], ['BTC', 'AGIX'], ['BTC', 'ATA'], ['BTC', 'GTC'], ['BTC', 'BAKE'], ['BTC', 'KLAY'], ['BTC', 'BOND'], ['BTC', 'MLN'], ['BTC', 'QUICK'], ['BTC', 'C98'], ['BTC', 'CLV'], ['BTC', 'QNT'], ['BTC', 'FLOW'], ['BTC', 'MINA'], ['BTC', 'FARM'], ['BTC', 'ALPACA'], ['BTC', 'MBOX'], ['BTC', 'WAXP'], ['BTC', 'PROM'], ['BTC', 'DYDX'], ['BTC', 'GALA'], ['BTC', 'ILV'], ['BTC', 'YGG'], ['BTC', 'FIDA'], ['BTC', 'AGLD'], ['BTC', 'RAD'], ['BTC', 'BETA'], ['BTC', 'RARE'], ['BTC', 'SSV'], ['BTC', 'LAZIO'], ['BTC', 'CHESS'], ['BTC', 'DAR'], ['BTC', 'BNX'], ['BTC', 'MOVR'], ['BTC', 'CITY'], ['BTC', 'ENS'], ['BTC', 'QI'], ['BTC', 'PORTO'], ['BTC', 'PLA'], ['BTC', 'PYR'], ['BTC', 'RNDR'], ['BTC', 'ALCX'], ['BTC', 'SANTOS'], ['BTC', 'MC'], ['BTC', 'BICO'], ['BTC', 'FLUX'], ['BTC', 'VOXEL'], ['BTC', 'HIGH'], ['BTC', 'CVX'], ['BTC', 'PEOPLE'], ['BTC', 'JOE'], ['BTC', 'ACH'], ['BTC', 'IMX'], ['BTC', 'GLMR'], ['BTC', 'LOKA'], ['BTC', 'API3'], ['BTC', 'ACA'], ['BTC', 'XNO'], ['BTC', 'WOO'], ['BTC', 'ALPINE'], ['BTC', 'GMT'], ['BTC', 'KDA'], ['BTC', 'APE'], ['BTC', 'MULTI'], ['BTC', 'ASTR'], ['BTC', 'MOB'], ['BTC', 'NEXO'], ['BTC', 'GAL'], ['BTC', 'LDO'], ['BTC', 'OP'], ['BTC', 'STG'], ['BTC', 'GMX'], ['BTC', 'POLYX'], ['BTC', 'APT'], ['BTC', 'OSMO'], ['BTC', 'HFT'], ['BTC', 'HOOK'], ['BTC', 'MAGIC'], ['BTC', 'RPL'], ['BTC', 'GNS'], ['BTC', 'SYN'], ['BTC', 'LQTY'], ['BTC', 'ID'], ['BTC', 'ARB'], ['BTC', 'RDNT'], ['BTC', 'EDU'], ['BTC', 'SUI'], ['ETH', 'QTUM'], ['ETH', 'EOS'], ['ETH', 'SNT'], ['ETH', 'BNT'], ['ETH', 'BNB'], ['ETH', 'LRC'], ['ETH', 'ZRX'], ['ETH', 'FUN'], ['ETH', 'NEO'], ['ETH', 'IOTA'], ['ETH', 'LINK'], ['ETH', 'XVG'], ['ETH', 'MTL'], ['ETH', 'ETC'], ['ETH', 'ZEC'], ['ETH', 'DASH'], ['ETH', 'TRX'], ['ETH', 'POWR'], ['ETH', 'XRP'], ['ETH', 'ENJ'], ['ETH', 'XMR'], ['ETH', 'BAT'], ['ETH', 'LSK'], ['ETH', 'MANA'], ['ETH', 'ADX'], ['ETH', 'ADA'], ['ETH', 'XLM'], ['ETH', 'LTC'], ['ETH', 'WAVES'], ['ETH', 'ELF'], ['ETH', 'RLC'], ['ETH', 'IOST'], ['ETH', 'STEEM'], ['ETH', 'ZIL'], ['ETH', 'WAN'], ['ETH', 'ZEN'], ['ETH', 'THETA'], ['ETH', 'IOTX'], ['ETH', 'QKC'], ['ETH', 'SC'], ['ETH', 'DENT'], ['ETH', 'HOT'], ['ETH', 'VET'], ['ETH', 'WBTC'], ['ETH', 'SCRT'], ['ETH', 'AAVE'], ['ETH', 'SLP'], ['ETH', 'GRT'], ['ETH', 'DEXE'], ['ETH', 'BETH'], ['ETH', 'UFT'], ['ETH', 'PUNDIX'], ['ETH', 'AXS'], ['ETH', 'FTM'], ['ETH', 'SOL'], ['ETH', 'SSV'], ['ETH', 'SAND'], ['ETH', 'DOT'], ['ETH', 'MATIC'], ['ETH', 'AVAX'], ['ETH', 'CHR'], ['ETH', 'GALA'], ['ETH', 'ATOM'], ['ETH', 'EGLD'], ['ETH', 'ICP'], ['ETH', 'NEAR'], ['ETH', 'ONE'], ['ETH', 'ROSE'], ['ETH', 'UNI'], ['ETH', 'XTZ'], ['ETH', 'CRV'], ['ETH', 'KAVA'], ['ETH', 'BETA'], ['ETH', 'GMT'], ['ETH', 'RUNE'], ['ETH', 'APE'], ['ETH', 'ALGO'], ['ETH', 'SNX'], ['ETH', 'LIT'], ['ETH', 'PEOPLE'], ['ETH', 'OP'], ['ETH', 'FIL'], ['ETH', 'ARPA'], ['ETH', 'HIFI'], ['ETH', 'APT'], ['ETH', 'WBETH'], ['USDT', 'BTC'], ['USDT', 'ETH'], ['USDT', 'BNB'], ['USDT', 'NEO'], ['USDT', 'LTC'], ['USDT', 'QTUM'], ['USDT', 'ADA'], ['USDT', 'XRP'], ['USDT', 'EOS'], ['USDT', 'TUSD'], ['USDT', 'IOTA'], ['USDT', 'XLM'], ['USDT', 'ONT'], ['USDT', 'TRX'], ['USDT', 'ETC'], ['USDT', 'ICX'], ['USDT', 'NULS'], ['USDT', 'VET'], ['USDT', 'USDC'], ['USDT', 'LINK'], ['USDT', 'WAVES'], ['USDT', 'ONG'], ['USDT', 'HOT'], ['USDT', 'ZIL'], ['USDT', 'ZRX'], ['USDT', 'FET'], ['USDT', 'BAT'], ['USDT', 'XMR'], ['USDT', 'ZEC'], ['USDT', 'IOST'], ['USDT', 'CELR'], ['USDT', 'DASH'], ['USDT', 'OMG'], ['USDT', 'THETA'], ['USDT', 'ENJ'], ['USDT', 'MATIC'], ['USDT', 'ATOM'], ['USDT', 'TFUEL'], ['USDT', 'ONE'], ['USDT', 'FTM'], ['USDT', 'ALGO'], ['USDT', 'DOGE'], ['USDT', 'DUSK'], ['USDT', 'ANKR'], ['USDT', 'WIN'], ['USDT', 'COS'], ['USDT', 'MTL'], ['USDT', 'TOMO'], ['USDT', 'PERL'], ['USDT', 'DENT'], ['USDT', 'KEY'], ['USDT', 'DOCK'], ['USDT', 'WAN'], ['USDT', 'FUN'], ['USDT', 'CVC'], ['USDT', 'CHZ'], ['USDT', 'BAND'], ['USDT', 'BUSD'], ['USDT', 'XTZ'], ['USDT', 'REN'], ['USDT', 'RVN'], ['USDT', 'HBAR'], ['USDT', 'NKN'], ['USDT', 'STX'], ['USDT', 'KAVA'], ['USDT', 'ARPA'], ['USDT', 'IOTX'], ['USDT', 'RLC'], ['USDT', 'CTXC'], ['USDT', 'BCH'], ['USDT', 'TROY'], ['USDT', 'VITE'], ['USDT', 'EUR'], ['USDT', 'OGN'], ['USDT', 'DREP'], ['USDT', 'WRX'], ['USDT', 'BTS'], ['USDT', 'LSK'], ['USDT', 'BNT'], ['USDT', 'LTO'], ['USDT', 'MBL'], ['USDT', 'COTI'], ['USDT', 'STPT'], ['USDT', 'WTC'], ['USDT', 'DATA'], ['USDT', 'SOL'], ['USDT', 'CTSI'], ['USDT', 'HIVE'], ['USDT', 'CHR'], ['USDT', 'BTCUP'], ['USDT', 'BTCDOWN'], ['USDT', 'ARDR'], ['USDT', 'MDT'], ['USDT', 'STMX'], ['USDT', 'KNC'], ['USDT', 'LRC'], ['USDT', 'PNT'], ['USDT', 'COMP'], ['USDT', 'SC'], ['USDT', 'ZEN'], ['USDT', 'SNX'], ['USDT', 'ETHUP'], ['USDT', 'ETHDOWN'], ['USDT', 'ADAUP'], ['USDT', 'ADADOWN'], ['USDT', 'VTHO'], ['USDT', 'DGB'], ['USDT', 'GBP'], ['USDT', 'SXP'], ['USDT', 'MKR'], ['USDT', 'DCR'], ['USDT', 'STORJ'], ['USDT', 'BNBUP'], ['USDT', 'BNBDOWN'], ['USDT', 'MANA'], ['USDT', 'YFI'], ['USDT', 'BAL'], ['USDT', 'BLZ'], ['USDT', 'IRIS'], ['USDT', 'KMD'], ['USDT', 'JST'], ['USDT', 'ANT'], ['USDT', 'CRV'], ['USDT', 'SAND'], ['USDT', 'OCEAN'], ['USDT', 'NMR'], ['USDT', 'DOT'], ['USDT', 'LUNA'], ['USDT', 'RSR'], ['USDT', 'PAXG'], ['USDT', 'WNXM'], ['USDT', 'TRB'], ['USDT', 'SUSHI'], ['USDT', 'YFII'], ['USDT', 'KSM'], ['USDT', 'EGLD'], ['USDT', 'DIA'], ['USDT', 'RUNE'], ['USDT', 'FIO'], ['USDT', 'UMA'], ['USDT', 'BEL'], ['USDT', 'WING'], ['USDT', 'UNI'], ['USDT', 'OXT'], ['USDT', 'SUN'], ['USDT', 'AVAX'], ['USDT', 'FLM'], ['USDT', 'ORN'], ['USDT', 'UTK'], ['USDT', 'XVS'], ['USDT', 'ALPHA'], ['USDT', 'AAVE'], ['USDT', 'NEAR'], ['USDT', 'FIL'], ['USDT', 'INJ'], ['USDT', 'AUDIO'], ['USDT', 'CTK'], ['USDT', 'AKRO'], ['USDT', 'AXS'], ['USDT', 'HARD'], ['USDT', 'STRAX'], ['USDT', 'UNFI'], ['USDT', 'ROSE'], ['USDT', 'AVA'], ['USDT', 'XEM'], ['USDT', 'SKL'], ['USDT', 'GRT'], ['USDT', 'JUV'], ['USDT', 'PSG'], ['USDT', '1INCH'], ['USDT', 'REEF'], ['USDT', 'OG'], ['USDT', 'ATM'], ['USDT', 'ASR'], ['USDT', 'CELO'], ['USDT', 'RIF'], ['USDT', 'TRU'], ['USDT', 'CKB'], ['USDT', 'TWT'], ['USDT', 'FIRO'], ['USDT', 'LIT'], ['USDT', 'SFP'], ['USDT', 'DODO'], ['USDT', 'CAKE'], ['USDT', 'ACM'], ['USDT', 'BADGER'], ['USDT', 'FIS'], ['USDT', 'OM'], ['USDT', 'POND'], ['USDT', 'DEGO'], ['USDT', 'ALICE'], ['USDT', 'LINA'], ['USDT', 'PERP'], ['USDT', 'SUPER'], ['USDT', 'CFX'], ['USDT', 'TKO'], ['USDT', 'PUNDIX'], ['USDT', 'TLM'], ['USDT', 'BAR'], ['USDT', 'FORTH'], ['USDT', 'BAKE'], ['USDT', 'BURGER'], ['USDT', 'SLP'], ['USDT', 'SHIB'], ['USDT', 'ICP'], ['USDT', 'AR'], ['USDT', 'POLS'], ['USDT', 'MDX'], ['USDT', 'MASK'], ['USDT', 'LPT'], ['USDT', 'XVG'], ['USDT', 'ATA'], ['USDT', 'GTC'], ['USDT', 'ERN'], ['USDT', 'KLAY'], ['USDT', 'PHA'], ['USDT', 'BOND'], ['USDT', 'MLN'], ['USDT', 'DEXE'], ['USDT', 'C98'], ['USDT', 'CLV'], ['USDT', 'QNT'], ['USDT', 'FLOW'], ['USDT', 'TVK'], ['USDT', 'MINA'], ['USDT', 'RAY'], ['USDT', 'FARM'], ['USDT', 'ALPACA'], ['USDT', 'QUICK'], ['USDT', 'MBOX'], ['USDT', 'FOR'], ['USDT', 'REQ'], ['USDT', 'GHST'], ['USDT', 'WAXP'], ['USDT', 'GNO'], ['USDT', 'XEC'], ['USDT', 'ELF'], ['USDT', 'DYDX'], ['USDT', 'IDEX'], ['USDT', 'VIDT'], ['USDT', 'USDP'], ['USDT', 'GALA'], ['USDT', 'ILV'], ['USDT', 'YGG'], ['USDT', 'SYS'], ['USDT', 'DF'], ['USDT', 'FIDA'], ['USDT', 'FRONT'], ['USDT', 'CVP'], ['USDT', 'AGLD'], ['USDT', 'RAD'], ['USDT', 'BETA'], ['USDT', 'RARE'], ['USDT', 'LAZIO'], ['USDT', 'CHESS'], ['USDT', 'ADX'], ['USDT', 'AUCTION'], ['USDT', 'DAR'], ['USDT', 'BNX'], ['USDT', 'MOVR'], ['USDT', 'CITY'], ['USDT', 'ENS'], ['USDT', 'KP3R'], ['USDT', 'QI'], ['USDT', 'PORTO'], ['USDT', 'POWR'], ['USDT', 'VGX'], ['USDT', 'JASMY'], ['USDT', 'AMP'], ['USDT', 'PLA'], ['USDT', 'PYR'], ['USDT', 'RNDR'], ['USDT', 'ALCX'], ['USDT', 'SANTOS'], ['USDT', 'MC'], ['USDT', 'BICO'], ['USDT', 'FLUX'], ['USDT', 'FXS'], ['USDT', 'VOXEL'], ['USDT', 'HIGH'], ['USDT', 'CVX'], ['USDT', 'PEOPLE'], ['USDT', 'OOKI'], ['USDT', 'SPELL'], ['USDT', 'JOE'], ['USDT', 'ACH'], ['USDT', 'IMX'], ['USDT', 'GLMR'], ['USDT', 'LOKA'], ['USDT', 'SCRT'], ['USDT', 'API3'], ['USDT', 'BTTC'], ['USDT', 'ACA'], ['USDT', 'XNO'], ['USDT', 'WOO'], ['USDT', 'ALPINE'], ['USDT', 'T'], ['USDT', 'ASTR'], ['USDT', 'GMT'], ['USDT', 'KDA'], ['USDT', 'APE'], ['USDT', 'BSW'], ['USDT', 'BIFI'], ['USDT', 'MULTI'], ['USDT', 'STEEM'], ['USDT', 'MOB'], ['USDT', 'NEXO'], ['USDT', 'REI'], ['USDT', 'GAL'], ['USDT', 'LDO'], ['USDT', 'EPX'], ['USDT', 'OP'], ['USDT', 'LEVER'], ['USDT', 'STG'], ['USDT', 'LUNC'], ['USDT', 'GMX'], ['USDT', 'POLYX'], ['USDT', 'APT'], ['USDT', 'OSMO'], ['USDT', 'HFT'], ['USDT', 'PHB'], ['USDT', 'HOOK'], ['USDT', 'MAGIC'], ['USDT', 'HIFI'], ['USDT', 'RPL'], ['USDT', 'PROS'], ['USDT', 'AGIX'], ['USDT', 'GNS'], ['USDT', 'SYN'], ['USDT', 'VIB'], ['USDT', 'SSV'], ['USDT', 'LQTY'], ['USDT', 'AMB'], ['USDT', 'BETH'], ['USDT', 'USTC'], ['USDT', 'GAS'], ['USDT', 'GLM'], ['USDT', 'PROM'], ['USDT', 'QKC'], ['USDT', 'UFT'], ['USDT', 'ID'], ['USDT', 'ARB'], ['USDT', 'LOOM'], ['USDT', 'OAX'], ['USDT', 'RDNT'], ['USDT', 'WBTC'], ['USDT', 'EDU'], ['USDT', 'SUI'], ['USDT', 'AERGO'], ['USDT', 'PEPE'], ['USDT', 'FLOKI'], ['USDT', 'AST'], ['USDT', 'SNT'], ['USDT', 'COMBO'], ['BNB', 'NEO'], ['BNB', 'IOTA'], ['BNB', 'XLM'], ['BNB', 'LTC'], ['BNB', 'ZIL'], ['BNB', 'ADA'], ['BNB', 'EOS'], ['BNB', 'THETA'], ['BNB', 'XRP'], ['BNB', 'TRX'], ['BNB', 'ETC'], ['BNB', 'VET'], ['BNB', 'FET'], ['BNB', 'XMR'], ['BNB', 'ZEC'], ['BNB', 'CELR'], ['BNB', 'DASH'], ['BNB', 'MATIC'], ['BNB', 'ATOM'], ['BNB', 'ONE'], ['BNB', 'FTM'], ['BNB', 'ALGO'], ['BNB', 'ANKR'], ['BNB', 'WIN'], ['BNB', 'COS'], ['BNB', 'CHZ'], ['BNB', 'HBAR'], ['BNB', 'STX'], ['BNB', 'KAVA'], ['BNB', 'ARPA'], ['BNB', 'BCH'], ['BNB', 'COTI'], ['BNB', 'SOL'], ['BNB', 'CTSI'], ['BNB', 'CHR'], ['BNB', 'SXP'], ['BNB', 'SNX'], ['BNB', 'RUNE'], ['BNB', 'ANT'], ['BNB', 'SAND'], ['BNB', 'OCEAN'], ['BNB', 'DOT'], ['BNB', 'RSR'], ['BNB', 'PAXG'], ['BNB', 'SUSHI'], ['BNB', 'EGLD'], ['BNB', 'BEL'], ['BNB', 'UNI'], ['BNB', 'AVAX'], ['BNB', 'BAKE'], ['BNB', 'CAKE'], ['BNB', 'XVS'], ['BNB', 'AAVE'], ['BNB', 'NEAR'], ['BNB', 'FIL'], ['BNB', 'INJ'], ['BNB', 'CTK'], ['BNB', 'AXS'], ['BNB', 'HARD'], ['BNB', 'ICP'], ['BNB', 'POLS'], ['BNB', 'MASK'], ['BNB', 'LPT'], ['BNB', 'KLAY'], ['BNB', 'QNT'], ['BNB', 'FLOW'], ['BNB', 'MINA'], ['BNB', 'RAY'], ['BNB', 'MBOX'], ['BNB', 'WAXP'], ['BNB', 'DYDX'], ['BNB', 'GALA'], ['BNB', 'ILV'], ['BNB', 'BETA'], ['BNB', 'DAR'], ['BNB', 'BNX'], ['BNB', 'ENS'], ['BNB', 'LINK'], ['BNB', 'LRC'], ['BNB', 'LOKA'], ['BNB', 'HIGH'], ['BNB', 'MC'], ['BNB', 'WOO'], ['BNB', 'PEOPLE'], ['BNB', 'IDEX'], ['BNB', 'GMT'], ['BNB', 'BSW'], ['BNB', 'APE'], ['BNB', 'IMX'], ['BNB', 'FUN'], ['BNB', 'GAL'], ['BNB', 'KNC'], ['BNB', 'OP'], ['BNB', 'HOOK'], ['BNB', 'ID'], ['BNB', 'EDU'], ['BNB', 'SUI'], ['BNB', 'COMBO'], ['TUSD', 'BTC'], ['TUSD', 'ETH'], ['TUSD', 'BNB'], ['TUSD', 'XRP'], ['TUSD', 'ADA'], ['TUSD', 'LTC'], ['TUSD', 'ARB'], ['TUSD', 'ID'], ['TUSD', 'LDO'], ['TUSD', 'MATIC'], ['TUSD', 'OP'], ['TUSD', 'SOL'], ['TUSD', 'SSV'], ['TUSD', 'RDNT'], ['TUSD', 'DOGE'], ['TUSD', 'EDU'], ['TUSD', 'SUI'], ['TUSD', 'PEPE'], ['TUSD', 'FLOKI'], ['USDC', 'BNB'], ['USDC', 'BTC'], ['USDC', 'ETH'], ['BUSD', 'BNB'], ['BUSD', 'BTC'], ['BUSD', 'XRP'], ['BUSD', 'ETH'], ['BUSD', 'LTC'], ['BUSD', 'LINK'], ['BUSD', 'ETC'], ['BUSD', 'TRX'], ['BUSD', 'EOS'], ['BUSD', 'XLM'], ['BUSD', 'ADA'], ['BUSD', 'BCH'], ['BUSD', 'QTUM'], ['BUSD', 'VET'], ['BUSD', 'EUR'], ['BUSD', 'ICX'], ['BUSD', 'BNT'], ['BUSD', 'ATOM'], ['BUSD', 'DASH'], ['BUSD', 'NEO'], ['BUSD', 'WAVES'], ['BUSD', 'XTZ'], ['BUSD', 'BAT'], ['BUSD', 'ENJ'], ['BUSD', 'ONT'], ['BUSD', 'RVN'], ['BUSD', 'ALGO'], ['BUSD', 'TOMO'], ['BUSD', 'XMR'], ['BUSD', 'ZEC'], ['BUSD', 'DATA'], ['BUSD', 'SOL'], ['BUSD', 'CTSI'], ['BUSD', 'HBAR'], ['BUSD', 'MATIC'], ['BUSD', 'WRX'], ['BUSD', 'ZIL'], ['BUSD', 'KNC'], ['BUSD', 'LRC'], ['BUSD', 'IQ'], ['BUSD', 'GBP'], ['BUSD', 'DGB'], ['BUSD', 'COMP'], ['BUSD', 'SXP'], ['BUSD', 'SNX'], ['BUSD', 'STORJ'], ['BUSD', 'MKR'], ['BUSD', 'RUNE'], ['BUSD', 'MANA'], ['BUSD', 'DOGE'], ['BUSD', 'ZRX'], ['BUSD', 'FIO'], ['BUSD', 'AVA'], ['BUSD', 'IOTA'], ['BUSD', 'BAL'], ['BUSD', 'YFI'], ['BUSD', 'BLZ'], ['BUSD', 'JST'], ['BUSD', 'SRM'], ['BUSD', 'ANT'], ['BUSD', 'CRV'], ['BUSD', 'SAND'], ['BUSD', 'OCEAN'], ['BUSD', 'NMR'], ['BUSD', 'DOT'], ['BUSD', 'LUNA'], ['BUSD', 'IDEX'], ['BUSD', 'RSR'], ['BUSD', 'PAXG'], ['BUSD', 'TRB'], ['BUSD', 'SUSHI'], ['BUSD', 'KSM'], ['BUSD', 'EGLD'], ['BUSD', 'DIA'], ['BUSD', 'BEL'], ['BUSD', 'WING'], ['BUSD', 'CREAM'], ['BUSD', 'UNI'], ['BUSD', 'AVAX'], ['BUSD', 'CAKE'], ['BUSD', 'XVS'], ['BUSD', 'ALPHA'], ['BUSD', 'VIDT'], ['BUSD', 'AAVE'], ['BUSD', 'NEAR'], ['BUSD', 'FIL'], ['BUSD', 'INJ'], ['BUSD', 'AERGO'], ['BUSD', 'ONE'], ['BUSD', 'AUDIO'], ['BUSD', 'CTK'], ['BUSD', 'KP3R'], ['BUSD', 'AXS'], ['BUSD', 'HARD'], ['BUSD', 'CVP'], ['BUSD', 'STRAX'], ['BUSD', 'FOR'], ['BUSD', 'UNFI'], ['BUSD', 'FRONT'], ['BUSD', 'ROSE'], ['BUSD', 'SYS'], ['BUSD', 'PROM'], ['BUSD', 'SKL'], ['BUSD', 'GHST'], ['BUSD', 'DF'], ['BUSD', 'JUV'], ['BUSD', 'PSG'], ['BUSD', 'DEXE'], ['BUSD', 'TUSD'], ['BUSD', 'CKB'], ['BUSD', 'TWT'], ['BUSD', 'LIT'], ['BUSD', 'SFP'], ['BUSD', 'FXS'], ['BUSD', 'DODO'], ['BUSD', 'BAKE'], ['BUSD', 'UFT'], ['BUSD', '1INCH'], ['BUSD', 'BAND'], ['BUSD', 'GRT'], ['BUSD', 'IOST'], ['BUSD', 'OMG'], ['BUSD', 'REEF'], ['BUSD', 'ACM'], ['BUSD', 'AUCTION'], ['BUSD', 'PHA'], ['BUSD', 'TVK'], ['BUSD', 'BADGER'], ['BUSD', 'FIS'], ['BUSD', 'OM'], ['BUSD', 'POND'], ['BUSD', 'DEGO'], ['BUSD', 'ALICE'], ['BUSD', 'CHZ'], ['BUSD', 'BIFI'], ['BUSD', 'LINA'], ['BUSD', 'PERP'], ['BUSD', 'SUPER'], ['BUSD', 'CFX'], ['BUSD', 'XVG'], ['BUSD', 'TKO'], ['BUSD', 'TLM'], ['BUSD', 'HOT'], ['BUSD', 'BAR'], ['BUSD', 'FORTH'], ['BUSD', 'BURGER'], ['BUSD', 'SLP'], ['BUSD', 'SHIB'], ['BUSD', 'ICP'], ['BUSD', 'AR'], ['BUSD', 'POLS'], ['BUSD', 'MDX'], ['BUSD', 'MASK'], ['BUSD', 'LPT'], ['BUSD', 'CELR'], ['BUSD', 'ATM'], ['BUSD', 'ZEN'], ['BUSD', 'FTM'], ['BUSD', 'THETA'], ['BUSD', 'WIN'], ['BUSD', 'KAVA'], ['BUSD', 'ATA'], ['BUSD', 'GTC'], ['BUSD', 'TORN'], ['BUSD', 'COTI'], ['BUSD', 'SC'], ['BUSD', 'CHR'], ['BUSD', 'STMX'], ['BUSD', 'FTT'], ['BUSD', 'DOCK'], ['BUSD', 'ERN'], ['BUSD', 'KLAY'], ['BUSD', 'UTK'], ['BUSD', 'IOTX'], ['BUSD', 'BOND'], ['BUSD', 'MLN'], ['BUSD', 'LTO'], ['BUSD', 'ADX'], ['BUSD', 'QUICK'], ['BUSD', 'C98'], ['BUSD', 'CLV'], ['BUSD', 'QNT'], ['BUSD', 'FLOW'], ['BUSD', 'XEC'], ['BUSD', 'MINA'], ['BUSD', 'RAY'], ['BUSD', 'FARM'], ['BUSD', 'ALPACA'], ['BUSD', 'ORN'], ['BUSD', 'MBOX'], ['BUSD', 'WAXP'], ['BUSD', 'MTL'], ['BUSD', 'OGN'], ['BUSD', 'DYDX'], ['BUSD', 'ELF'], ['BUSD', 'GALA'], ['BUSD', 'SUN'], ['BUSD', 'ILV'], ['BUSD', 'REN'], ['BUSD', 'YGG'], ['BUSD', 'STX'], ['BUSD', 'FET'], ['BUSD', 'ARPA'], ['BUSD', 'LSK'], ['BUSD', 'FIDA'], ['BUSD', 'DENT'], ['BUSD', 'AGLD'], ['BUSD', 'RAD'], ['BUSD', 'HIVE'], ['BUSD', 'STPT'], ['BUSD', 'BETA'], ['BUSD', 'RARE'], ['BUSD', 'TROY'], ['BUSD', 'CHESS'], ['BUSD', 'SCRT'], ['BUSD', 'CELO'], ['BUSD', 'DAR'], ['BUSD', 'BNX'], ['BUSD', 'LAZIO'], ['BUSD', 'OXT'], ['BUSD', 'MOVR'], ['BUSD', 'CITY'], ['BUSD', 'ENS'], ['BUSD', 'ANKR'], ['BUSD', 'QI'], ['BUSD', 'POWR'], ['BUSD', 'JASMY'], ['BUSD', 'AMP'], ['BUSD', 'PLA'], ['BUSD', 'PYR'], ['BUSD', 'RNDR'], ['BUSD', 'ALCX'], ['BUSD', 'MC'], ['BUSD', 'BICO'], ['BUSD', 'FLUX'], ['BUSD', 'REQ'], ['BUSD', 'VOXEL'], ['BUSD', 'COS'], ['BUSD', 'CTXC'], ['BUSD', 'HIGH'], ['BUSD', 'CVX'], ['BUSD', 'PEOPLE'], ['BUSD', 'OOKI'], ['BUSD', 'MDT'], ['BUSD', 'NULS'], ['BUSD', 'SPELL'], ['BUSD', 'JOE'], ['BUSD', 'DUSK'], ['BUSD', 'ACH'], ['BUSD', 'IMX'], ['BUSD', 'GLMR'], ['BUSD', 'UMA'], ['BUSD', 'LOKA'], ['BUSD', 'API3'], ['BUSD', 'ACA'], ['BUSD', 'XNO'], ['BUSD', 'WOO'], ['BUSD', 'TFUEL'], ['BUSD', 'T'], ['BUSD', 'ASTR'], ['BUSD', 'GMT'], ['BUSD', 'KDA'], ['BUSD', 'APE'], ['BUSD', 'ALPINE'], ['BUSD', 'BSW'], ['BUSD', 'SANTOS'], ['BUSD', 'MULTI'], ['BUSD', 'PORTO'], ['BUSD', 'BTTC'], ['BUSD', 'MBL'], ['BUSD', 'MOB'], ['BUSD', 'NEXO'], ['BUSD', 'GAL'], ['BUSD', 'LDO'], ['BUSD', 'EPX'], ['BUSD', 'STEEM'], ['BUSD', 'CVC'], ['BUSD', 'REI'], ['BUSD', 'DREP'], ['BUSD', 'AKRO'], ['BUSD', 'PUNDIX'], ['BUSD', 'LUNC'], ['BUSD', 'USTC'], ['BUSD', 'OP'], ['BUSD', 'OG'], ['BUSD', 'KEY'], ['BUSD', 'ASR'], ['BUSD', 'FIRO'], ['BUSD', 'NKN'], ['BUSD', 'WBTC'], ['BUSD', 'LEVER'], ['BUSD', 'GLM'], ['BUSD', 'SSV'], ['BUSD', 'STG'], ['BUSD', 'ARK'], ['BUSD', 'BETH'], ['BUSD', 'LOOM'], ['BUSD', 'SNM'], ['BUSD', 'AMB'], ['BUSD', 'PHB'], ['BUSD', 'GAS'], ['BUSD', 'PROS'], ['BUSD', 'VIB'], ['BUSD', 'GMX'], ['BUSD', 'AGIX'], ['BUSD', 'SNT'], ['BUSD', 'POLYX'], ['BUSD', 'APT'], ['BUSD', 'QKC'], ['BUSD', 'OSMO'], ['BUSD', 'HFT'], ['BUSD', 'HOOK'], ['BUSD', 'MAGIC'], ['BUSD', 'RPL'], ['BUSD', 'GFT'], ['RUB', 'BTC'], ['RUB', 'ETH'], ['RUB', 'XRP'], ['RUB', 'BNB'], ['RUB', 'BUSD'], ['RUB', 'USDT'], ['RUB', 'LTC'], ['RUB', 'ADA'], ['RUB', 'MATIC'], ['RUB', 'DOT'], ['RUB', 'SOL'], ['RUB', 'ARPA'], ['RUB', 'ALGO'], ['RUB', 'NEO'], ['RUB', 'NEAR'], ['RUB', 'ARB'], ['TRY', 'BTC'], ['TRY', 'BNB'], ['TRY', 'BUSD'], ['TRY', 'ETH'], ['TRY', 'XRP'], ['TRY', 'USDT'], ['TRY', 'LINK'], ['TRY', 'SXP'], ['TRY', 'AVAX'], ['TRY', 'TRX'], ['TRY', 'CHZ'], ['TRY', 'XLM'], ['TRY', 'DOGE'], ['TRY', 'DOT'], ['TRY', 'ADA'], ['TRY', 'HOT'], ['TRY', 'NEO'], ['TRY', 'EOS'], ['TRY', 'RVN'], ['TRY', 'ONT'], ['TRY', 'VET'], ['TRY', 'SHIB'], ['TRY', 'MATIC'], ['TRY', 'SOL'], ['TRY', 'GRT'], ['TRY', 'TLM'], ['TRY', 'ARPA'], ['TRY', 'LAZIO'], ['TRY', 'REEF'], ['TRY', 'MANA'], ['TRY', 'SAND'], ['TRY', 'PORTO'], ['TRY', 'SLP'], ['TRY', 'LRC'], ['TRY', 'SANTOS'], ['TRY', 'BEL'], ['TRY', 'DENT'], ['TRY', 'ENJ'], ['TRY', 'ALICE'], ['TRY', 'GALA'], ['TRY', 'LUNA'], ['TRY', 'FTM'], ['TRY', 'MINA'], ['TRY', 'XTZ'], ['TRY', 'ATOM'], ['TRY', 'ICP'], ['TRY', 'ROSE'], ['TRY', 'BTTC'], ['TRY', 'COS'], ['TRY', 'ONE'], ['TRY', 'SPELL'], ['TRY', 'AXS'], ['TRY', 'DAR'], ['TRY', 'NEAR'], ['TRY', 'ALPINE'], ['TRY', 'INJ'], ['TRY', 'API3'], ['TRY', 'MBOX'], ['TRY', 'UMA'], ['TRY', 'TWT'], ['TRY', 'APE'], ['TRY', 'JASMY'], ['TRY', 'FIL'], ['TRY', 'ZIL'], ['TRY', 'GMT'], ['TRY', 'WAVES'], ['TRY', 'BSW'], ['TRY', 'AUDIO'], ['TRY', 'GAL'], ['TRY', 'ENS'], ['TRY', 'ALGO'], ['TRY', 'STORJ'], ['TRY', 'ETC'], ['TRY', 'ANKR'], ['TRY', 'APT'], ['TRY', 'FET'], ['TRY', 'CFX'], ['TRY', 'STX'], ['TRY', 'AGIX'], ['TRY', 'ARB'], ['TRY', 'ID'], ['TRY', 'JOE'], ['TRY', 'MAGIC'], ['TRY', 'ACH'], ['TRY', 'XVS'], ['TRY', 'EDU'], ['TRY', 'SUI'], ['TRY', 'RNDR'], ['TRY', 'OG'], ['TRY', 'PEPE'], ['TRY', 'FLOKI'], ['TRY', 'CITY'], ['TRY', 'COMBO'], ['TRY', 'LTC'], ['TRY', 'RAD'], ['EUR', 'BTC'], ['EUR', 'ETH'], ['EUR', 'BNB'], ['EUR', 'XRP'], ['EUR', 'LINK'], ['EUR', 'DOT'], ['EUR', 'LTC'], ['EUR', 'ADA'], ['EUR', 'BCH'], ['EUR', 'YFI'], ['EUR', 'XLM'], ['EUR', 'GRT'], ['EUR', 'EOS'], ['EUR', 'DOGE'], ['EUR', 'EGLD'], ['EUR', 'AVAX'], ['EUR', 'CHZ'], ['EUR', 'ENJ'], ['EUR', 'MATIC'], ['EUR', 'THETA'], ['EUR', 'WIN'], ['EUR', 'VET'], ['EUR', 'TRX'], ['EUR', 'SHIB'], ['EUR', 'ETC'], ['EUR', 'SOL'], ['EUR', 'ICP'], ['EUR', 'RUNE'], ['EUR', 'LAZIO'], ['EUR', 'PORTO'], ['EUR', 'ALPINE'], ['EUR', 'ATOM'], ['EUR', 'GALA'], ['EUR', 'NEAR'], ['EUR', 'WAVES'], ['EUR', 'APE'], ['EUR', 'GMT'], ['EUR', 'FTM'], ['EUR', 'GAL'], ['EUR', 'DAR'], ['EUR', 'OP'], ['EUR', 'APT'], ['EUR', 'ARB'], ['EUR', 'ID'], ['EUR', 'EDU'], ['EUR', 'SUI'], ['ZAR', 'BTC'], ['ZAR', 'ETH'], ['ZAR', 'BUSD'], ['GBP', 'BTC'], ['GBP', 'ETH'], ['GBP', 'XRP'], ['GBP', 'BNB'], ['GBP', 'LINK'], ['GBP', 'DOGE'], ['GBP', 'DOT'], ['GBP', 'ADA'], ['GBP', 'CHZ'], ['GBP', 'LTC'], ['GBP', 'VET'], ['GBP', 'MATIC'], ['GBP', 'SOL'], ['GBP', 'RUNE'], ['UAH', 'BTC'], ['UAH', 'USDT'], ['UAH', 'BNB'], ['UAH', 'ETH'], ['UAH', 'BUSD'], ['UAH', 'LTC'], ['BIDR', 'BTC'], ['BIDR', 'ETH'], ['BIDR', 'BNB'], ['BIDR', 'BUSD'], ['BIDR', 'USDT'], ['BIDR', 'ZIL'], ['BIDR', 'TKO'], ['BIDR', 'DOGE'], ['BIDR', 'MATIC'], ['BIDR', 'ADA'], ['BIDR', 'XRP'], ['BIDR', 'SOL'], ['DAI', 'BTC'], ['DAI', 'ETH'], ['DAI', 'BNB'], ['DAI', 'USDT'], ['DAI', 'BUSD'], ['BRL', 'BTC'], ['BRL', 'USDT'], ['BRL', 'ETH'], ['BRL', 'BNB'], ['BRL', 'BUSD'], ['BRL', 'XRP'], ['BRL', 'LINK'], ['BRL', 'LTC'], ['BRL', 'DOGE'], ['BRL', 'ADA'], ['BRL', 'DOT'], ['BRL', 'CHZ'], ['BRL', 'ENJ'], ['BRL', 'WIN'], ['BRL', 'MATIC'], ['BRL', 'SHIB'], ['BRL', 'SOL'], ['BRL', 'AVAX'], ['BRL', 'MANA'], ['BRL', 'GALA'], ['BRL', 'SAND'], ['PLN', 'BTC'], ['PLN', 'ETH'], ['PLN', 'BUSD'], ['PLN', 'USDT'], ['RON', 'BUSD'], ['RON', 'BTC'], ['RON', 'EGLD'], ['RON', 'USDT']]
```

as you can see, there are 374 nodes and 1376 edges.

i found the simplest code here:

```
cycles = []

def main():
  global graph
  global cycles
  for edge in graph:
    for node in edge:
      findNewCycles([node])
  for cy in cycles:
    path = [str(node) for node in cy]
    s = ",".join(path)
    print(s)

def findNewCycles(path):
  start_node = path[0]
  next_node= None
  sub = []

  #visit each edge and each node of each edge
  for edge in graph:
    node1, node2 = edge
    if start_node in edge:
      if node1 == start_node: next_node = node2
      else: next_node = node1
      if not visited(next_node, path):
        # neighbor node not on path yet
        sub = [next_node]
        sub.extend(path)
        # explore extended path
        findNewCycles(sub);
      elif len(path) > 2  and next_node == path[-1]:
        # cycle found
        p = rotate_to_smallest(path);
        inv = invert(p)
        if isNew(p) and isNew(inv):cycles.append(p)

def invert(path):
    return rotate_to_smallest(path[::-1])

#  rotate cycle path such that it begins with the smallest node
def rotate_to_smallest(path):
  n = path.index(min(path))
  return path[n:]+path[:n]

def isNew(path):return not path in cycles

def visited(node, path): return node in path

main()
```

i think it's clear, but there is performance issue, for my case, it cost too much time.

could you help on this? to get the correct answer within a standable time?

Comment: What is a standable time?  The 'graph' tag seems wrong.  Did you read the tag description?

Comment: lookup time is least if you use adjacency matrix instead of graph

Comment: @ravenspoint within 60 seconds, thanks, graph removed

Comment: You could ask this question in _CodeReview_ too (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you looked if [any of the `networkx` cycle tools works for you](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/cycles.html)?

Comment: OK.  If you post a link to your input then I will run it with my cycle finder and compare.  ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Cycles )  It is coded in C++ which is usually many times faster than python.

Comment: @LoukasPap If the OP is not the author of the code the question can't be asked on Code Review. The question says `I found this code`, not `I wrote this code`.

Comment: @AKX thanks very much, networkx is what i need!!!!